# I need help understanding how to get s stringified (variable) version of an SVG image

Tags: javascript, html, svg, var

I am currently working with an svg image that I need help stringifying, If that makes sense. Basically how to make the image open in a text/code editor as only variables?

Here is an example of what I am looking for:

```
var svgData='PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1MTIiIGhlaWdodD0iNTEyIiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiPjxkZWZzPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0ic3Ryb2tl
```

Currently when open an svg image in a text editor I just get something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG 
Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 255.1 227.3" style="enable-background:new 0 0 255.1 
227.3;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
```

Any help is welcome! Thank You.

Comment: SVG is an XML ... language, I guess you'd say. What you see in the editor is in fact the SVG code.

Comment: Look into base64 encoding, it might put you on the right path.

Comment: But what about the "var svgData"?

Comment: It's really not at all clear what you're asking here. What do you mean by "stringify"? Where do you expect that string of characters to come from? How do you expect to use it?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, the reason I asked in the first place is because I found many websites such as www.gtapixels.com/en/gallery that allow users to upload png images and output them in that "strange" svg data text format.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like svgData is cut a little short. But if I understand your question right, you want that encoded svgData available in a textarea?

You can use the native functions btoa and atob (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) to encode and decode the svg content.

For example using your svgData value: atob("PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1MTIiIGhlaWdodD0iNTEyIiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiPjxkZWZzPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0ic3Ryb2tl") = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="512" height="512" version="1.1"><defs><linearGradient id="stroke"`

and we can convert it back with:
btoa('`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="512" height="512" version="1.1"><defs><linearGradient id="stroke"`') = "PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1MTIiIGhlaWdodD0iNTEyIiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiPjxkZWZzPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0ic3Ryb2tlIg=="

Comment: I believe what you are explaining is correct. Basically this question came about after I saw websites such as this one: https://gtapixels.com/en/gallery

Comment: It allows users to download the images in that seemingly strange "variable" way through text files

Comment: OK. It looks like your text editor is recognizing the content is base64 encoded and automatically decoding it for you. What OS and text editor are you using? You can try opening it in something else to see if it doesnt decode it for you. Or if you open the developer tools in your browser you can use the functions I mentioned above to encode/decode the content yourself.